# Prelogin filter before j_security_check

Tags: jboss, j-security-check, jboss-portal

I currently have a form based login in my application which is developed on Jboss portal server. I wish to do some pre login validation and redirect user to another page in case of a condition being true.

How can I intercept the request before j_security_check login is executed and also forward the flow to j_security_check after that condition is found to be false.

Please note that I do not want to have client side validation.

This is what I was trying to do, but didn't find any success:

Created a LoginFilter.java file and my webapp web.xml looked like:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.xxx.filter.LoginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>j_security_check</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

but this filter is not being called at all.

Can anyone tell me what is the issue in this code or any alternative approach to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wont be able to intercept j_security_check from Serverside. Filters and all will be called only after j_security_check passed , if your resource is secured.

I had similar case , I changed the way my application was making calls. First make a http request to do j_security_check and then use same client instance to do rest of the work.

The bottom line is that , j_security_check is the first thing happens are server. So you wont be able to intercept it from Serverside.

Thanks
J