# Websphere pre-login to j_security_check

Tags: authentication, servlets, websphere, servlet-filters, j-security-check

I am using Websphere with j_security_check and I have a working login filter with CONFIDENTIAL and SSL settings. Due to some complex requirements, I need to process the j_username variable before performing j_security_check.

From one of the [answers found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678584/prelogin-filter-before-j-security-check), it was said that this pre-login processing cannot be done. However, I noted that the previous asker was using Tomcat, while I am using Websphere. I found that there is a solution for my problem [over here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.base.doc%2Finfo%2Faes%2Fae%2Ftsec_servlet.html) but it seems that everytime I try to login, I receive a "The website cannot display the page. The website has a programming error."

I tried troubleshooting by checking if the syntax was correct. Found some inconsistencies like  and corrected them as best I could. However, I still keep getting the same error.

Could someone throw me in the right direction? I can provide further info but they are mostly similar to the second link. The only protected folder is in \protected\ and the .java  servlet is located in \WEB-INF\classes.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a specific link in WAS 7.0 infocenter that you can point to  instead of the default home page for the infocenter? Also what is this complex requirement that mandates the access to j_security_check. Would using some javascripts be of any help?

Comment: [Edited Link Here.](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.base.doc%2Finfo%2Faes%2Fae%2Ftsec_servlet.html)

Oops. I went to their help page and started searching from there. I have edited it as above. I based my code off this page although I found some syntax error such as <filter id="Filter_1"> ending with </filter-id> which leaves me to believe that the page's codes aren't as reliable as it may seem to be.

Comment: There is an unfortunate requirement to encrypt the password sent from the client to the server, in spite of HTTPS and SSL. They would like to have a plain text password stored in AD while maintaining that the channel and data are both encrypted. Two methods I am thinking of trying. The first means that I have to encrypt the password at client side, send it to server, decrypt it at server side before comparing with AD. The other method is to hash the password client side, send it to server then have the server retrieve the password from AD and hash it before comparing the two.

Comment: Just an update. I checked the error logs and I realised that I used LoginFilter.java instead of LoginFilter.class which means I now have to try to figure out how to compile it using javac into a class file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is interested, the results are here:

For \WEB-INF\web.xml

```
<filter id="Filter_1">
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.myloginfilter.MyLoginFilter</filter-class>
    <description>Performs pre-login operation</description>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/j_security_check</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

For \WEB-INF\classes\com\myloginfilter\MyLoginFilter.class

```
    public class MyLoginFilter implements Filter {

    protected FilterConfig filterConfig;

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
       this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
    }

    public void destroy() {
       this.filterConfig = null;
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws java.io.IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(new MyRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request), response);
    }

    public static class MyRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

        public MyRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
            super(request);
        }

        @Override
        public String getParameter(String name) {
            String username= getRequest().getParameter("j_username");

            if ("j_password".equals(name) && "admin".equals(username)) {
                username = "administrator";
                return username;
            }
            return super.getParameter(name);
        }
    }
}
```

To compile it, use Javac with the command:

```
javac -cp servlet-api-2.3.jar MyLoginFilter.class
```

Comment: Does this really work? Normally the j_security_check is done *before* filters are executed.

Comment: Yes it does, at least for Tomcat as well as WebSphere.